# How can I get my app to recognize speech input to take a photo?

Tags: android, sdk, camera, voice

I am developing an app which takes photos with the use of the voice.  I have read the google sdk voice recognizer, but I haven't quite understood it. So here I am asking, what specifically can I add to my app with the use of the camera that will tell my app to listen for the word 'snap' in order to take a photo. I haven't found a real tutorial of it nor do I understand how to really code it by just looking in the android sdk.  I want to be able to open the camera, and then you click the listening button, and it waits for the user to say 'snap' then takes a photo, review it, then return back to the camera viewer.

Comment: Do you not know how to do any of the above, or just how to trigger the shutter by saying 'snap'?

Comment: I want to know how to trigger the shutter by saying 'snap'

Comment: Speech to text libraries.. filter out the word 'snap'...